# PHP: How do I write to a file without raising file permissions above 644?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, file-permissions

## Context

- Apache 2.4.18
- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- PHP 7.0.8
- WordPress 4.6 *(This may be irrelevant as this question is mainly just a PHP writing thing, but I **am** working within a WordPress theme's directory.)*

### Files

I have two files: `foo.php` and `bar.css`.

This is `foo.php` (located in `/wp-content/themes/theme-name/`):

```
<?php
// Write some stuff to bar.css
file_put_contents('abs/path/to/bar.css', 'Blah blah blah...');
?>
```

and `bar.css` is completely blank (also located in `/wp-content/themes/theme-name/`).

---

## Goal

I'd like to allow `foo.php` to write to `bar.css` *without* me having to up the permissions of the `bar.css` file to `666` (from `644`). I've tested it, and I *can* get it to work just fine if I change the permissions of `bar.css` to `666`, but again, that's something I'd like avoid.

---

## What I've tried

I know this might seem like a redundant question, but honestly, I've been looking on SO and beyond, and I still haven't found anything that fixes this. I mean, I've read around (such as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986734/how-do-i-make-644-permission-files-writable-from-php) or [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261707/how-do-you-permit-php-to-write-to-a-file-without-compromising-server-security), etc.) and maybe there's something I'm just not getting, but to my understanding based on things I've read is once I change the permissions to at least `644` and set the file owner to `www-data:www-data`, PHP should be able to write to it and life should be good. But... that's not happening.

The theme editor in the WordPress admin panel (`example.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=bar.css&theme=theme-name`) is able to write to `bar.css` even when it's at `644`... so what's the difference between that and what I'm trying to do? What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of file permissions?

Comment: Um... I don't know? I wouldn't think so? I mean, like I said, WordPress can do it from within the theme editor so, like I asked in the question... what's the difference? I genuinely don't know. Is this just a bad thing to attempt altogether?

Comment: Are you executing foo.php from the browser or from the command line?

Comment: @Derek Maybe it does and maybe I'm just misunderstanding. My line of reasoning was like this: "Well, 644 is more secure than 666, and other stuff seems to be able to write to the very same 644 file with no problem, so there's no need to raise it to 666 if the thing I want to be done can apparently be done with it still at 644." So I don't know, that's just what I was thinking.

Comment: @J_D The browser.

Comment: Ok, so if you can do it via the browser on one file then you should be good so long as the file owner is the same (which you stated it is). Do you see anything in the error log? Are you getting a white screen when you run foo.php? You can also write out to a variable, like $result = file_put_contents(blah, blah); then echo out $result to see if it returns the number of bytes written or false

Comment: No white screen, but I do see some stuff in the error log regarding the files in question saying stuff like, "Unable to open... .../wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.", and, "failed to open stream: Permission denied", so let me look into that a bit more. And thanks for the tips.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 Apache user out of the box is `www-data` so the permissions are guaranteed correct, especially considering the same user account is used to process the whole wordpress application. My guess is you're not referencing the file you think you are. Try `var_dump(file_exists('abs/path/to/bar.css'));` and possibly your `'abs/path/to/bar.css'` should have a leading slash `'/abs/path/to/bar.css'`